# After change SQL Aliases with SharePoint but Configuration Wizard doesn't work?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, administration

I have moved database to new SQL server, "Server2", and we did SQL Aliases in all SharePoint servers, like this post

[Using SQL Aliases with SharePoint](http://thomasvochten.com/archive/2009/03/using-sql-aliases-with-sharepoint/)

It happened almost 1 year ago. Now I am trying to run SharePoint Configuration Wizard giving below error. But application is working fine.

[image]
[image]

What could be the problem?

### Update:

Log errors after ran wizard

> SqlError: 'Cannot open database "SharePoint_Config" requested by the
> login. The login failed.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider'
> Number: 4060 State: 1 Class: 11 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 65536
> Server: 'Server1'    07/22/2013 13:25:32.73          OWSTIMER.EXE
> (0x0724)                             0x073C            Windows
> SharePoint Services           Database
> 880j     High    SqlError: 'Login failed for user
> 'Domain\sn_spappprod'.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider'
> Number: 18456 State: 1 Class: 14 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 65536
> Server: 'Server1'       07/22/2013 13:25:32.73          OWSTIMER.EXE
> (0x0724)                             0x073C            Windows
> SharePoint Services           Database
> 6y63    Critical SQL Database 'SharePoint_Config' on SQL Server
> instance 'Server1' not found. Additional error information from SQL
> Server is included below.  Cannot open database "SharePoint_Config"
> requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user
> 'Domain\sn_spappprod'.    07/22/2013 13:25:32.73          OWSTIMER.EXE
> (0x0724)                             0x073C            Windows
> SharePoint Services           Database
> 880k    High       at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
> command, CommandBehavior behavior)     at

It suppose to connect alias databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a permissions issue with the DOMAIN\sn_spappprod account. Does it have a SQL login with the necessary rights? If you have a multi server farm, do you have an alias on every server?

A nice trick to see if your user has access is to use a testfile, see the bottom section of [this article](http://thomasvochten.com/archive/2011/06/sql-aliases-in-the-real-world/) on how to do that. If that test returns no errors, your connection to the sql server is ok - be sure to use the alias name SERVER2 when running the test.

If the test returns an error, your alias probably is not configured correctly on the server.

It could also be that your account doesn't have the needed permissions to run the configuration wizard. Refer to the "Setup user administrator account" section in [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: How come application is working?

Comment: The application probably runs with different service accounts than the account you're using to run the configuration wizard - and they should be :)

Comment: OK. My admin is already out for the day. I will get back tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably on a 64bit OS while the Config Wizard is 32bit.

There is a 32bit and 64bit version of cliconfg. It is best to configure them in an identical way.

On a 64bit OS:

- cliconfg (64bit): **C:\windows\system32\cliconfg.exe**
- cliconfg (32bit): **C:\windows\syswow64\cliconfg.exe**